# SP 2013: How to create automated daily email?

Tags: 2013, workflow

Created ticketing system of sorts in SP 2013. Need to use designer workflows to create a daily email reminder for requests that are incomplete. Ideally email would send to all analysts that have items not equal to "Completed" and email body would include (for an individual analyst) a list of all requests that are not equal to "Completed". Current workflow looks like this

[image]

**note: My company does not grant permission for anyone in the company to write code in designer and our admin has left this week. I only have access to workflows and lists/libraries in designer.

Comment: Could you please specify exactly What's your issue in the above workflow steps?